# Do the attack helicopter's heat-seeking missiles lock on to ground targets?

Tags: battlefield-3

I have had success using the attack helicopter's heat-seeking missiles to take down jets and other helicopters, but I haven't been able to lock on to ground vehicles with them yet.  Have I been doing it wrong or is it not possible?

If they don't lock on to ground targets, then do the pilots ever get any missiles or upgrades that allow them to hit ground targets more easily?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No they do not.

Heat seeking missiles are air-air missiles.

Laser Guided Missiles are air-ground missiles.

There is also an upgrade that makes your regular rocket pods (attack helicopter) track targets a bit, making them more accurate from range.

Comment: Can pilots use the laser guided missiles or are those just for the gunners?

Comment: @Venesectrix It's for the pilot. The gunner gets the TV missiles

Comment: @Venesectrix I take back what I last said. The gunner gets the TV missiles and the Laser Guided missiles, the pilot of the Scout Choppers gets the laser guided missiles though.

Comment: laser guided are AGM, but also lock or anything laser illuminated.

Answer (score 0):

from BF3 website:

Heat seeking missiles

Heat seeking missiles that can lock on enemy air and ground targets.